# Python: Read HTML source from URL and get date into program

Tags: python, html, url

I'm a beginner at Python and I want to read info from a site and get some of the data as output in my textbox (I use EasyGUI).  I have found this to get the HTML source of a URL but now I want to work with the HTML output, I know how to work with XML and I guess it's a bit the same for HTML. Is there any way to work with the elements and attributes?

```
filehandle = urllib.urlopen('URL')

for lines in filehandle.readlines():
    print lines

filehandle.close()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you know how to work with xml. It's basicly the same. Parse the DOM. Check out BeautifulSoup or http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, Beautiful soup is a library that can help you. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download/2.x/documentation.html, shows a straightforward example.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read())
titleTag = soup.html.head.title
```

Python has a built in parser too. http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

BeautifulSoup is very good at handling broken html though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with jQuery's syntax to select HTML elements, you may find [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) useful.